# Can we make a conditional type that excludes (filters out) one member of a union type?

Tags: typescript

I have a union type, and would like to generically derive another type from it that excludes one of the possibilities from the union.

```
type Exclude<Excluded, Union> = Union extends Excluded | infer Rest ? Rest : Union;
type OneOfThree = string | number | object;
type NotString = Exclude<string, OneOfThree>;
let temp: NotString = "s";  // <-- compiles okay.
```

The snippet above doesn't work as I'd hoped. The type `NotString` evaluates to `string | number | object`. Is there a syntax that would allow subtracting a type from a union?

Comment: There's already [an `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) that works this way (although the inputs are in the other order); like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKV28m).  Is that what you're looking for?  It seems like quite a coincidence that your naming convention is so close to the linked documentation.

Comment: total coincidence. did not know that it existed.

that's a great page, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @jcalz pointed out, it turns out that there is a [utility type called Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) that does precisely that...

It expands to this expression:

```
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

This works. The reason why the answer is this simple (note: there are no `infer`), is because it takes into account the [distributivity rule](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

The key thing to observe is that when we pass in a union type as the `T` (in the above example), each member of that union is mapped independently to the right side,

so, e.g.

`Exclude<A|B, A>` becomes: `(A extends A ? never : A) | (B extends A ? never : A)`

which then reduces to `never | B`, or just `B`.